# django's post_save() and data from request

Tags: django

I desperately need to be able to get some information from the request array on post_save() for a certain model. Is it possible to do that somehow?

Comment: Not in any sane manner. Try another route.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's what I am going to do :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to [override the `save()` method](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) on that model and emit the post save signal along with the specific data you need to send. See [Sending Signals](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#sending-signals) to learn how.

An alternative (albeit a very dirty hackish way) would be to have an additional column in the model which saves the data you need to send out (although you would still have to override the `save()` method on the model).